# How to trigger BeforeUpdate event on a checkbox only?

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a form with a checkbox that requires a password in order to be ticked.

The problem is, after the event is finished and I click outside of the box it still asks me for a password.

Update: The event completes. If I click somewhere else it triggers again.

```vb
Private Sub Signed_by_Mike_BeforeUpdate(Cancel As Integer)
    If InputBox("You must provide the correct password to Lock or Unlock CheckBox!", "Password Input") <> "password" Then
        MsgBox "Wrong Password Entered. Operation aborted!", vbCritical
        Cancel = True
    End If
End Sub
```

I expected this event to take place only on the checkbox, but it does happen if I click anywhere in the form afterwards.

Comment: A thought: Rather than doing this kind of check, why don't you prompt for the password earlier (e.g. when the form is loaded), and then either show/hide or enable/disable the checkbox based on whether the password is correct? Also, if you're storing the password as plain text in your project, someone can always open up VBA to see it, bypassing your security in any case.

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your input. I need that password on the checkbox because there will be people completing the form and people approving the form. I did set up a login form for my database, but i can't find any information on how to code that and show the check box only for certain users

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're very close - only missing a mechanism to make it "remember" when the password was provided - you can use a `Static` local for this ("static" local variables keep their value between procedure calls), or a module-level variable:

```
Private Sub Signed_by_Mike_BeforeUpdate(Cancel As Integer)
    Static authorized As Boolean

    If Not authorized And InputBox("You must provide the correct password to Lock or Unlock CheckBox!", "Password Input") <> "password" Then
        MsgBox "Wrong Password Entered. Operation aborted!", vbCritical
        Cancel = False
    Else
        authorized = True    
    End If
End Sub
```

Shouldn't `Cancel` be set to `True` given the wrong password though?

Comment: Hi, Thank you for correcting my code. The problem is once i set Cancel to True for some reason once i click out of the checkbox the event is still triggered, even when i try to click design again on the form. And if i leave it as False, well it does not work properly.It does happen the same when i use your code as well.

Comment: The event would still fire, ...but the input box stops prompting for a password, no?

Comment: Yes, so the event fires and it's getting the job done. Problem is afterwards. If i try to update some other record or click somewhere else the event fires again. I find it strange because i am sure i only assigned it for the checkbox.

Answer (score 0):

well the BeforeUpdate event can be a tricky trigger point, particularly when using a messagebox input.   If you really need to use this approach try putting it in the AfterUpdate event and also try changing your syntax from: <> "password" to instead be: Not Like "password".  Also if this a continuous form type - that would be a complication.

but if you are still in design phase; my suggestion is to add a small, unlabeled, text box with a **** password mask, placed just below the check box.  Instruct the user to enter the pw into that textbox.  Then your code in the check box's AfterUpdate event is very simple: 
If me.checkbox = -1 then
If me.pw Not Like "pw" then
msgbox "wrong pw"
me.checkbox = 0
end if
end if